# How do i add action column with 'edit' and 'delete' buttons?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to add action column in the table with delete and edit buttons in it. Table in the image is output of the coded below. An action column is needed in the table in order to perform actions i.e edit and delete.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urj6S.png)

Code for the table

```
<b-table
      responsive
      class="mb-0"
      head-variant="light"
      :items="items"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      :per-page="perPage"
    >
      <template #cell(id)="data"> #{{ data.item.id }} </template>
      <template #cell(user)="data">
        <b-img
          :src="require('@/assets/images/users/' + data.item.user.image)"
          rounded="circle"
          :alt="data.item.user.image"
          width="40"
        />
        <span class="ml-2 fw-medium"
          >{{ data.item.user.first }} {{ data.item.user.last }}</span
        >
      </template>
      <template #cell(team)="data">
        <b-img
          :src="require('@/assets/images/users/' + data.item.team.teamimg1)"
          rounded="circle"
          :alt="data.item.team.teamimg1"
          width="35"
          class="mr-n2 border border-white"
        />
        <b-img
          :src="require('@/assets/images/users/' + data.item.team.teamimg2)"
          rounded="circle"
          :alt="data.item.team.teamimg2"
          width="35"
          class="mr-n2 border border-white card-hover"
        />
        <b-img
          :src="require('@/assets/images/users/' + data.item.team.teamimg3)"
          rounded="circle"
          :alt="data.item.team.teamimg3"
          width="35"
          class="border border-white"
        />
      </template>
      <template #cell(status)="data">
        <b-badge
          pill
          :class="`px-2 text-white badge bg-${data.item.status.statusbg}`"
        >
          <i class="font-9 mdi mdi-checkbox-blank-circle"></i>
          {{ data.item.status.statustype }}
        </b-badge>
      </template>
      <template #cell(action)="data">
        <b-button variant="light" @click="deleteUser(data.item.user.id)">
          <feather type="delete" class="feather-sm"></feather>
        </b-button>
      </template>
      
    </b-table>
```

Comment: I think you should add more information on whether the actions should be processed purely in JavaScript, or, send via POST to the backend

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use the `b-dropdown` element (more info [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown)). Your table would then have one column with an "action" description and have a b-dropdown button for each row:

```
<b-table
  responsive
  class="mb-0"
  head-variant="light"
  :items="items"
  :current-page="currentPage"
  :per-page="perPage"
>
  <template #cell(id)="data"> #{{ data.item.id }} </template>
  
  <!--......-->

  <template #cell(action)="data">
    
      <b-dropdown
          right
          variant="primary"
      >
          <template v-slot:button-content>
            Select One
          </template>

          <b-dropdown-item v-on:click="edit(data.item)">
            Edit
          </b-dropdown-item>

          <b-dropdown-item v-on:click="delete(data.item)">
            Delete
          </b-dropdown-item>
          
      </b-dropdown>

  </template>
  
</b-table>
```

Then, in your `methods`, just add:

```
edit: function(myObject) {
    console.log(myObject);
    //Do something here
},

delete: function(myObject) {
    console.log(myObject);
    //Do something here
},
```

You could also add one column for each edit and delete feature. In this case, simply create a normal `b-button` and just call the `v-on:click="edit(data.item)"` and `v-on:click="remove(data.item)"` the same way it was implemented on the `b-dropdown-item`s

Comment: Suggest me another solution please. This is not working.